# how display only single column in datagrid in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having multiple columns in database table but i want to display only one column from it in datagridview
I tried following code but its displaying whole table column

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/add-and-remove-columns-in-the-datagrid-using-the-designer?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Manually add the column to the grid in the designer or code. Set that columns `DataPropertyName` to match the column name in the `DataTable` you want to display. Then IN CODE, set `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false`.